# Modifying column header names in Master-Detail grid in Devexpress

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, master-detail

I have a Master-Detail set up with 2 grids.  On the master grid, I have the `ShowOnlyPredefinedDetails` option set to `false`.
This means that I see a little + sign that allows me to expand the details of the detail grid (in the master grid)[image].  I would like to rename 
some columns in that section as well as hide certain columns.  I'm using VB.NET How do I go about this.  See image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the grid control ViewRegistered event, from there you can modify the columns in that grid view that have columns within them that you want to modify, rename, or remove.  Here is an example, I hope that it helps:

```
 private void myGridControl_ViewRegistered(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.ViewOperationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            if (e.View != null)
            {
               //Inside of this statement you can adjust, add, and modify all of the columns inside of that grid that appears when you click on the +

                (e.View as GridView).Columns["myHiddenColumn"].Visible = false;
                (e.View as GridView).Columns.Add(new GridColumn() { Name = "AddColumn", Caption = "Name To Display", Visible = true, FieldName = "DataField"});
                (e.View as GridView).Columns["DataField"].OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
                (e.View as GridView).Columns["DataField"].OptionsColumn.AllowFocus = false;
                (e.View as GridView).Columns["DataField"].OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This worked.  The following is another solution that was provided by the Devexpress support team.

 `Private Sub gvClientGroup_MasterRowExpanded(sender As Object, e As CustomMasterRowEventArgs) Handles gvClientGroup.MasterRowExpanded

        gvClone = gvClientGroup.GetDetailView(e.RowHandle, e.RelationIndex)
        gvClone.Columns("ClientNoGroup").Visible = False
        gvClone.Columns("oldName").Caption = "newName"

End Sub`

Comment: When I try to export the gridView to PDF, only the current selected row is exported with the right amount of fields and with the right renamed fields. This is the code I use.  How would I export all the rows with the right amount of fields and with all of them renamed. 

`gvClone.OptionsPrint.ExpandAllDetails = True
gvClone.ExportToPdf("gvCloneViewData.pdf")`

Comment: You can enable the multi select of a grid with the following code:

`gridView.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;`

This should export all of the rows that you select.  If you want to always export every row, then you would need to programatically select all of the rows before you export to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is create a second grid view for your details.  If you haven't already done this, do the following:

1. In your grid designer, click "Retrieve Details" if you have not already done so.  This will cause the designer to recognize that you have a second level in your bound object:

[image]

2. Once you see the second layer, now you need a new grid view for it.  Click on "Click here to change view" and select "Create a new view" and pick "GridView."

[image]

Now you will see both grid views from the designer, and clicking on one or the other will change the context of the menus to the left:

[image]

For example, if you have `gridView2` selected, when you click on the "Layout" menu, it will show the current layout for your detail grid rather than the master grid.  From here, you can remove or add columns as you see fit.  Likewise, from the "Columns" menu you will see the new columns (you may have to add them to the view by dragging them over), and you can change the `Caption` property to change the text of the title.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [Data Annotation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument18273) attributes with properties of your data-classes to declare how you data should be displayed in GridControl:

To skip column generation for the specific property you can mark this property with the `<DisplayAttribute(AutoGenerateField := false)>` declaration.

To prevent column from displaying you can mark this property with the `<DisplayAttribute(Order := -1)>` declaration. Later, user can show this column via Column Chooser UI.

To specify the column caption use the `<DisplayAttribute(Name := "YOUR CAPTION")>` declaration.

You can also control filtering/editing/formatting and validation capabilities.

Related Links:

- [Tutorial: Create and Manage Data in Code and Apply Data Annotation Attributes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsQLc0-j7dk&index=6&list=PL8h4jt35t1wi5Syuitp41Sbc8H-cAVtEX)
- [Video Tutorial: Create and Manage Data in Code and Apply Data Annotation Attributes](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114704)